# radius of symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: limits, markov-chains, limsup-and-liminf

How to calculate the radius of the symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $\limsup_k (p^{(k)}(0,0))^\frac{1}{k}$?

($p^{(k)}(0,0)$ denotes the probability to get from $0$ to $0$ in $k$ steps and the transition probabilities of the symmetric random walk are $p(n,n+1)=p(n,n-1)=\frac{1}{2}$.)

Comment: I don't understand why you would call the expression you wrote down the radius, but you can get $p^{(k)}(0,0)$ from the binomial distribution.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the binomial distribution to obtain $p^{(k)}(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

When $k$ is odd, $p^{(k)}(0,0)$ is zero.

When $k$ is even, $p^{(k)}(0,0) = \frac{1}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2}$. From [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas), 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty } \binom{k}{k/2}^{1/k}  =2$$
Hence, $\limsup_{k\to\infty } p^{(k)}(0,0)^{1/k} = 1$.